# Performing a postgresql query using js but using a variable to find records with dates<certain value

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Essentially what I want to do in my .js file is query for records created in the last hour in a postgreSQL table. I currently have a variable named time and which holds the date for the last hour (ie time='2015-09-03 14:55:15').

Right now I have, which works:

```
var query = client.query("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, created_at WHERE created_at>'2015-09-04 14:55:15' FROM users");
```

But what I really want to do is have the query search for records in the last hour using the time variable - how would I accomplish this? My initial thought was to do this but it is incorrect:

```
var query = client.query("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, created_at WHERE created_at>"+time+" FROM users");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is in Node.JS.

A few issues:

First, are you sure the first example works? You have the SQL clauses as "SELECT WHERE FROM". Normally the order is "SELECT FROM WHERE".

Second, the string in your second example is missing the single quotes from the first example. If you look at the string you're passing to `query`, it will look something like this:

> SELECT firstname, lastname, email, created_at WHERE created_at>Thu Sep 03 2015 16:12:17 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) FROM users

Without the single quotes, that is definitely not valid SQL.

Third, the format of the date that is generated by JavaScript may not be valid for use in Postgres. I tried it on a Postgres 9.2 instance I have here and got the following error:

> ERROR: time zone "gmt-0400" not recognized

So you may need to add some code to properly format the date as a Postgres date literal.

A better alternative to formatting and string concatenation would be to use [a parameterized query](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#method-query-parameterized).

Comment: My apologies, it is:
var query = client.query("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, created_at FROM users WHERE created_at>'2015-09-04 14:55:15'"); This works in PostgreSQL! I have the time variable equal to that date format and it works as the created_at column in postgresql is a timestamp without timezone

Comment: Oh I think i got it! I simply had to do -> WHERE created_at>'$time'. thanks for the help :)